# Are there filename limitations when transferring files to an android device using MTP on Windows?

Tags: windows, android, mtp

I've got Samsung tab s7 for reading, and today I've tried transferring books to it. This ended in a partial failure, and I don't completely understand why.

I will start with the example that started it all (maybe there is something specific about it that I have missed), and then proceed to a bit of investigation.

So the situation is as follows:

1. I have a number of directories with books on my pc.
2. I had a pre-existing "Documents" folder in my "Internal storage" on the tablet
3. I have created a "\Books\Humble Bundle" path inside the "Documents" folder
4. I am trying to copy a folder structure named "Humble Book Bundle Software Development by O'Reilly\97 Things Every Programmer Should Know" into the "Humble Bundle" folder
5. The folder contains three files: cover.jpg, description.txt and a "Kevlin Henney (Editor) - 97 Things Every Programmer Should Know_ Collective Wisdom from the Experts (2010, O’Rei.pdf"
6. When trying to copy the above, an error sound is played in Windows, but no message is presented. On the tablet, there is now an expected folder structure and two files: cover.jpg and description.txt. The pdf file is missing. I should also note that if there were additional folders to copy after this one, they will not be copied, as the process stops after this "error".

Now, to some tests:

1. The most obvious idea is that there is some kind of a filename length limitation that is not made clear. So let's try deleting one character at a time from the pdf filename. It goes through when 7 symbols are deleted ("Kevlin Henney (Editor) - 97 Things Every Programmer Should Know_ Collective Wisdom from the Experts (2010.pdf")
2. Now, is this a limitation in the transfer process or the android filesystem itself? I try to copy the file into the \Humble Bundle\ folder, which is successful, then create "Humble Bundle\Humble Book Bundle Software Development by O'Reilly\97 Things Every Programmer Should Know" folder and move the file there using the tablet's file manager. This is also successful. So this is not an issue with the Android filesystem.
3. Is this an issue with windows explorer perhaps? I repeat the tests in Total Commander: same results. This implies that either the MTP protocol is to blame, or windows API/driver that works with it.
4. I will note that the maximum folder name length that I can set in both explorer and built-in samsung file manager is **128**. I don't know if this is significant, as my file names do not exceed this number.
5. (The following tests are in the windows explorer) When I try to create a folder with max name length in the "\Books\Humble Bundle" folder, I can create a folder with 128 characters in the name as expected. However, when I try to create a new folder inside, I can only set a name to **71** characters.
6. If I keep going and create a new folder even lower \Books\Humble Bundle\[128 chars]\[71 chars]\, I can create a folder with 128 characters again, but it shows up as "New Folder" on the tablet.
7. If I create any new folder in this "New Folder" on the tablet itself, it shows up on PC until I back out of the "New Folder" (that is showing up as 128 character folder on PC). After that, I can no longer see it if I go back.
8. If I rename "New Folder" on the tablet (even to the max limit of 128), I can access the folder inside again.

The worst part is that these numbers don't make any sense (other that 128 in a way, I guess). Documents\Books\Humble Bundle\[128 chars]\[71 chars]\ is 230 characters total including slashes. This is not the number you expect to see when looking for edge cases.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I just want to move my books to the tablet without manually renaming every file and/or folder.

Comment: The MTP specification does not seem to specify a maximum path length. Therefore I assume on Windows the programmer of MTP simply used the default ´MAX_PATH´ constant which is on Windows 260 characters. The difference to 230 may be caused by the fact that Windows Explorer uses internally uses a slightly longer path for MTP devices as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68021793/150978). My recommendation would be to use a bootable Live Linux DVD/stick and check if the behavior is different on Linux.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have also just tried setting LongPathsEnabled in registry to 1, but that didn't change anything.
Unfortunately I don't have a usb stick available right now, so I will try this method later.

On the other hand I wonder if max_path would be relevant in this situation? My main fs is ntfs, and I assume that Android is not using FAT either

Comment: Changing `LongPathsEnabled` only enables longer paths for Windows file-related API functions (which are not used by MTP as MTP is not a file-system on Windows). Also this only enables the API methods to use longer path, but the maximum buffer size is usually compiled into each program so the program or in this case the Explorer MTP plugin have to provide longer buffers to be able to use it.

Comment: I just made a quick test and was able to copy (up and down) an MP3 file in a folder with [128]\[81]\[124].mp3 Using Windows 10 21H1 + Pixel 4a Android 11.